# Unsecure resources on Security SE Post

Tags: support, ssl

[This post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82362/in-citizenfour-what-was-snowden-mitigating-with-head-blanket), when viewed in HTTPS, is triggering security warnings:

Using Firefox, I got the classical yellow triangle warning in the address bar, caused by this `img` tag with absolute URI source in HTTP:

```
<img alt="Snowden pulling blanket over his head" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDeLe.png">
```

In Chrome, I got the grey shield warning and this error in console:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   '[In CitizenFour, what was Edward Snowden mitigating with a head blanket?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82362/in-citizenfour-what-was-snowden-mitigating-with-head-blanket)'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://stackexchange.com/ads/beta-question/js?id=beta-ad-container'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Including HTTP resources in a page served in HTTPS is generally considered an issue https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content

Should that be fixed?

Comment: it can be, just propose an edit to the post, replacing the "http" by "https" - it's supported but the default values are bad because SE doesn't default to https (and thus doesn't enforce https'ing share links and imgur embedded links).

Comment: @SEJPM right. I can't change less than 6 chars though, so I left a comment ansking the poster to do so. Then, we'll still have the other issue with the ads js.

Comment: @MarioTrucco You can add this to the body: `<!-- comment to make this long enough to edit -->` It will not show up in the post.